# Access file in script-scm from groovy pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a groovy pipeline script checked into scm and loaded from jenkins.

The script is supposed to load a config file, fine-tuning its behavior. The config file is in the same directory as the script.

Can I somehow access this directory from the script? The working directory is set to the workspace, which is not where the script is located. Maybe I can somehow extract the directory of the script itself?